# Under what circumstances is $ \mathbb Z[\alpha] $ closed under the Galois action?

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory

Let $ \mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha) $ be a finite Galois extension with primitive element $ \alpha $ (with minimal polynomial $ f_\alpha $) and Galois group $ G $.

Is $ \mathbb Z[\alpha] \subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha) $ always closed under the Galois action? Or is there some necessary and sufficient criterion for this property? Equivalently:

- Under what circumstances is $ \sigma(x) \in \mathbb Z[\alpha] $ for all $ x \in \mathbb Z[\alpha] $ and $ \sigma \in G $?
- Under what circumstances are all the roots of $ f_\alpha $ in $ \mathbb Z[\alpha] $?
- (Rephrasing of the previous one: Under what circumstances can we associate to every root $ \beta $ of $ f_\alpha $ a polynomial $ g_\beta \in \mathbb Z[X] $ such that $ \beta = g_\beta(\alpha) $?)

I was not able to prove that it holds for all finite Galois extensions, but I was also unable to come up with a counterexample.

Edit: After playing with Sage for a bit, I found out that of the $ 979709 $ polynomials with coefficients between $ 0 $ and $ 100 $, only $ 99 $ give a 'normal' extension of $ \mathbb Z $.

Answer (score 4):

I think this may be true for quadratic extensions, but in a cubic the following (somewhat natural) counterexample comes to mind.

Let $r=2\cos(2\pi/9)$. It is a zero of the cubic $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$. The other zeros of $f(x)$ are $2\cos(4\pi/9)=r^2-2$ and $2\cos(8\pi/9)=(r^2-2)^2-2=-[r+(r^2-2)]=2-r-r^2$.
These are then each others Galois conjugates. The Galois group is generated by the automorphism $\sigma$ determined by $\sigma(r)=r^2-2$.

Let $\alpha=2r$. Then $\sigma(\alpha)=2(r^2-2)=\dfrac12\alpha^2-4$. This is not an element of $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$. We see that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^3-6x+8$, implying that all the elements of $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ have the form
$a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ with some (uniquely determined) integer coefficients $a,b,c$.

Comment: I thought that a quadratic like $u=(1+\sqrt2)/3$ might also work but in that case $6u^2-5u=(1-\sqrt2)/3$. The argument in the answer needs the fact that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Multiplying an algberaic integer $r$ that has this property by a large enough integer (here $2$) may similarly produce a number $\alpha$ that no longer has it? I cannot think of a tool for diagnosing this :-(

Comment: Thanks! After toying with sage for a bit, I saw that in most cases $ \mathbb Z[\alpha] $ is not closed under the Galois action, but after scaling $ \alpha $ by a large enough factor it does have the property (but then you lose some elements, of course)

Comment: Oooh, now I see what you meant with scaling. I think scaling will indeed produce a non-normal extension.